# nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, hibernate

hi all i have question,

i have tried to hit my endpoint, my entity like this

```
@Builder
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address extends Audit implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

@Column(name = "firstAddress", nullable = false)
private String firstAddress;

@Column(name = "secondAddress", nullable = false)
private String secondAddress;

@Column(name = "city", nullable = false)
private String city;

}
```

but when i hit with my postman like this

```
{
  "firstAddress": "panda street 5",
  "secondAddress": "Mentari 5",
  "city": "Semarang"
}
```

i got error like this, i think this error because of data integrity for ID. cannot generate Identity on my Entity

```
DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [id" of relation "address]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

this is my service

```
public interface AddressService {

    Address insert(Vendor vendor);
}
```

@Service

```
public class AddressServiceImpl implements AddressService {
    private AddressRepository addressRepository;
    public AddressServiceImpl(AddressRepository addressRepository) {
        this.addressRepository = addressRepository;
    }
@Override
    public Address insert(Address address) {
        if (address == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Address can't be null");
        }
        return address Repository.save(vendor);
    }
}
```

here my repo

```
public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Address> {

}
```

Comment: Please add the full exception stacktrace instead of a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove the line from id field

@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)

you have already defined it as primary key by adding @Id and it is auto generated as well

moreover, I would suggest to use GenerationType.AUTO instead of IDENTITY, you can refer more details at https://thorben-janssen.com/jpa-generate-primary-keys